# Is there away to pass variables into the "children" props for react-apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-client

Wondering if there is a way to pass additional data into the function that the UI is triggering the mutation with. Please see below for an example.

```
        <Mutation 
            mutation={COMPLETE_EVALUATION}
            variables={{studentId:courses.course.studentId, courseId: courses.course.courseId, passed:true, checkpoints:courses.evals}}>
             {(completeEval, {error, loading}) => (
                <div className="competency-actions ml-32 mr-64">
                    <Button className="w-128 mr-16 pass-button" variant="contained" onClick={() => completeEval(true)}>
                        PASS
                    </Button>
                    <Button className="w-128 ml-16 fail-button" variant="contained" onClick={() => completeEval(false)}>
                        REMEDIATE
                    </Button>
                </div>
            )} 
        </Mutation>
```

I would like to provide additional information to the mutation based on the button clicked. Am I going down the right path or is there another way I could accomplish setting that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter passed to the `Mutation` component's render props function is a `mutate` function. This function can be called with no additional arguments, but it can also accept an options object. This options object can have the following properties:

- `variables`
- `optimisticResponse`
- `refetchQueries`
- `update`

These options are identical to the props that can be passed directly to the `Mutation` component. In fact, if an option is provided through the `mutate` function, it will override its counterpart `Mutation` component prop if one was also provided.

What this means is that you can **omit** the `variables` prop in your component, and instead pass in the variables when calling the `mutate` function:

```
completeEval({
  variables: {
    studentId:courses.course.studentId,
    courseId: courses.course.courseId,
    checkpoints:courses.evals,
    passed: true,
  }
})
```

See the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#render-prop-function-1) for more info.

Comment: That is so cool, thank you Daniel! I updated my Mutation to remove the variables prop and pass it in with the function. I'll try to dig a little deeper into the docs in the future, it's hard to find exactly what i'm looking for sometimes :)